Cell without salt bridge nor porous surface - ions in same aqueous solution - What's the name reference of these cells?
I've seen an unusual type of cell, where the main reaction is $A_{(s)}+B_{(s)} = A^+_{(aq)}+B^-_{(aq)}$, on a YouTube seminar on electrochemistry presented by Geoff McConohy.
The cell has the peculiarity of not having a salt bridge, nor a porous surface, that separates the two electrolytic solutions.
The seminar speaker calls it a "formation cell", but after searching this term in Google I don't find any match, any reference.

What are called these type of cells, please?
Could it be that this presented cell is just a thought experiment, imagined to illustrate a concept but without any physical reality?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66123/why-cant-a-galvanic-cell-be-a-single-cell https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109480/why-cant-an-electrochemical-cell-be-a-single-cell

Not having a salt bridge, and having one solution that both electrodes are in rather than two separate solutions, is pretty typically for all electrolytic cells (cells where electricity provides the energy for a chemical reaction; you're probably more familiar with galvanic cells, which create energy as a result of the chemical reaction).

The described device is called a pseudocapacitor.
Note that there is no sharp difference between capacitors and electrochemical cells. Advanced supercapacitors bridge the gap.

From cursory check, it looks like electrolytic capacitors have oxide layer, while this is like a lemon battery.

@Mithoron Thanks, I found a more suitable word and edited to correct.

I still think you're overthinking this. OP practically answered it by himself with this picture - it's an electrochemical cell for electroplating.

@Mithoron Isn't electroplating supposed to be an irreversible process? Here, arrows show both directions.

Hmm, now that I looked on this thing, there's "B-", like metal would make anion in this thing! Either it's a nonsense, or OP is not telling us way too much, or both.

@Mithoron https://patents.google.com/patent/US4083757A/en

$\ce{MnSO4 + 2H2O → MnO2 + H2SO4 + H2}$

I bet it is a real thing but isn't optimal for commercial batteries. I'm not an expert, though.
